# How to import many .MOV files to Sony Vegas?

Tags: video-editor, editing, vegas-pro

I have a problem with Sony Vegas. When ever I import too many .MOV files, Sony Vegas Pro 13, doesn't accept them, so they are black in the preview screen.

However, if I import only 4 or 5 .MOV files to Vegs, it accepts them and I can see the clips in the preview screen. But when I go over that limit of 4 or 5, Sony Vegas doesn't accept the .MOV files, and now all of the clips are black in preview.

How do I make it so that I can import as many .MOV files as I want to SonyVegas.

I have Quicktime installed and also unchecked the option in preferences>video that says something like close media when other apps are open.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known problem](https://www.vegascreativesoftware.info/us/forum/help-limited-number-of-imported-clips--84777/). Quicktime for Windows is 32-bit only, and that presents a memory ceiling for the QT handler/decoder. What's worked for me, including in a current project, where I'm working with hundreds of of 5D MkIII files, is to import in batches. Once done, I have no issues loading or working with the project even if many of those are used on the timeline. I should say that often I'm able to import many clips without needing to divide the import step into batches.

As suggested in the linked forum thread, try rolling back to [QT 7.6.2](http://filehippo.com/download_quicktime_player/5704/) or [Quicktime Alternative](http://filehippo.com/download_quicktime_alternative/6077/), and see if that provides a more permanent solution.

Comment: What do you mean by batches? Does it mean to combining several .MOV clips together and then importing? If it does mean that, how *do* you combines several clips together?

Comment: Importing a few clips. Saving project. Exiting Vegas.Opening project. Importing a few more..etc